# How to store sorted set of objects in redis?

Tags: redis, hash, sortedset

I would like to know how to store a list of objects in Redis. That is I have a key like this.

```
users:pro
{ 
name: "Bruce", age: "20", score: 100,
name: "Ed", age: "22", score: 80
}
```

Where I will want to store a list of hashes as value of a particular key. I would like to use the `score` field as the score field in the sorted set. How could I accomplish this?

I have seen writing a putting a single hash for a key, but what if I want multiple hashes and one of the hash fields must act as a score field for the sorted set?

Comment: just store it... redis doesn't care what the type is.

Comment: @Jasen how to store it? The command `HSET` only is capable of storing only one hash, now how to store multiple hashes in the same key?

Comment: maybe you could store the whole list under one hash... redis doesn't do multiple indices.

Comment: @Jasen could you answer the question? I ain't able to understand because I am new to `Redis`

Answer (score 8):

Using a single key to store all your hashes will require some serialization as Redis doesn't support nested data structures. The result would be the following:

```
key: users:pro
         |
         +-----> field       value
                 name:Bruce  "age: 20, score: 100"
                 name:Ed     "age: 22, score: 80"

> HMSET users:pro name:Bruce "age: 20, score: 100" name:Ed "age:22, score:80"
```

The corresponding Sorted Set would be:

```
key: users:pro.by_scores
         |
         +---> scores:    80           100
         +---> values: "name:Ed"   "name:Bruce"

> ZADD users:pro.by_scores 80 "name:Ed" 100 "name:Bruce"
```

**Note 1**: this approach mandates a unique ID per-user, currently the `name` property is used which could be problematic.

**Note 2**: to avoid the serialization (and deserialization), you can consider using a dedicated key per user. That means doing:

```
key: users:pro:Bruce
         |
         +-----> field       value
                 age         20
                 score       100

key: users:pro:Ed
         |
         +-----> field       value
                 age         22
                 score       80

> HMSET users:pro:Bruce age 20 score 100
> HMSET users:pro:Ed age 22 score 80

key: users:pro.by_scores
         |
         +---> scores:      80                100
         +---> values: "users:pro:Ed"   "users:pro:Bruce"

> ZADD users:pro.by_scores 80 "users:pro:Ed" 100 "users:pro:Bruce"
```

Comment: So instead of `users:pro:Ed`, I must use `users:pro:101` where `101` is the unique id.

Comment: Yep - definitely a better and safer approach. I would also recommend including the id in the hash itself as a separate field (i.e. `HSET users:pro:101 id 101`) - despite the "denormalization", this makes it much easier to work with the data.