# Redis Store JSON or Hash in Sorted Sets - sorted by Time

Tags: redis

I am able to store JSON with the Redis Commander GUI, but I am not sure how to add a JSON object via Redis Terminal CLI to a Redis sorted set that uses timestamps. If I am correct, everything is stored as strings which explains the string returned from the sorted set query.

### Redis Sorted Set

```
key: teams
score: 10
value: {
  "timestamp": "2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
  "name": "Lakers",
  "conference": "West"
}
```

### Redis-CLI Command & Result

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE teams 10 10
1) "{\r\n  \"timestamp\": \"2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z\",\r\n  \"name\": \"Lakers\",\r\n  \"conference\": \"West\"\r\n}"
```

I was considering using a Unique ID for a separate Hash map of all the different objects. In the sorted set, I would use a timestamp as the score and UID for the object. 
Reference: [How to store sorted set of objects in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614975/how-to-store-sorted-set-of-objects-in-redis)

What is the preferred way of doing this in Redis?

Comment: Did you consider using redisjson?

Comment: If I use Redis JSON, would I even need the sorted set?

Comment: If you still want to get the results sorted then you would still need to use SortedSet, we plan to add secondary index/sort support to RedisJSON soon

Comment: You can try FastoRedis PRO, Rejson module